# How to make all images look same

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web developing, and forgive me if this is very naive question but I am facing an issue where I have a row which has 7 images basically certification that My company has. They all are different size and color and doesnt look good together. 
I am trying to make them all look same size and responsive. 
So far I have used:

```
  clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
```

but this just cuts the images, so I need some other solution which can fix this
My first image is 250*100px whereas other is 250*250px likewise I have 7 images all different size so I have set max-width:250px; height:auto; and this is how it look now:

CSS:

```
.ribbon img{
        height:150px;
        margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    }

.ribbon img:hover{
    border: solid 1px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;

    }
.ribbon{
    vertical-align:center;
    }
```

What I am trying to get is those first to image should come in center I have tried vertical-align:middle but doesn't work and the PCGS image is full size 250*250 so it is the problem

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want them all to have the same height?

Comment: Use a parent div for each image, set those divs to be inline-blocks. Then set your images inside the parent divs to be max-width:100% and max-height:100%. Then set vertical-align:middle ?

Comment: @rahul ! see updated answer below. This will work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `img { height: 250px; }` to makes all img with the same height, browser will handle the width onscale if you leave the `width` not set

### Edit 1 -

If you want they have the same width, you may replace the `height` with `width` that setup the value you want, please try this example, https://jsfiddle.net/e7wv86pc/

`img { width: 14%; }`

Comment: I might adjust that further, to something like `.cert-img { height: 75px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }` just to ensure that everything lines up nicely.

Comment: I tried your solution but it now sets my image with random width and breaks the pixels

Comment: @Rahul.Valani Hi Rahul, please see edit 1, that would be great if we have more information/requirement

Comment: @ZayLau I tried this but it doesn't make my images come in center, please see my edited question.

Comment: @Rahul.Valani Hi Rahul, may I know which one are you going for? setting the width/height? you may want to try my https://jsfiddle.net/e7wv86pc/ that displaying the example of Edit 1

Comment: Yup this works great I aligned image accordingly but Have a doubt on mobile view my images gets too small is there any way the in mobile view instead of gettign the 7th image in second row I get three images 
so in mobile view image1 image2 image3 image4 and then in second row image5 image6 image7

Comment: @Rahul.Valani Hi Rahul, please check out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp for query media if you are interested in developing responsive css (mobile view). Please also checkout http://getbootstrap.com/ for Bootstrap which is a great framework to implement responsive website :) if you want the desktop and mobile remain the same version, try `increase the width to 28%` that makes the logos take 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can also use css property `background-size` set to `cover`, and set the images using css `background-image` property like this:

```css
.image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; 
}

.i1 {
  background-image: url("http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjE4NDMwMzc4Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDg4Nzg4Mg@@._V1_UY317_CR6,0,214,317_AL_.jpg");
}

.i2 {
  background-image: url("http://feelgrafix.com/data_images/out/20/932835-gerard-butler.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="image i1"></div>
<div class="image i2"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this it makes my image which is 250*100px into 250*250 and breaks the pixels

Comment: What you mean by **breaks the pixels**? It will fit the image according to the target size, if it is small it will resize it to fit the size, if it is too large it will also resize it to the target size. It is not what you want?